# What system-electronic components or physic mechanism is used to modulate signals between different devices used in lithography?

Tags: lithography, modulation

I know that pattern generator *device* (no pattern generator *software*) is needed to generate a model signal system that help you use electron diffraction for wafer surface printing by the use of the TEM. These signals are templates called *patterns* and is generated by some electronic unknown components inside of pattern generator, maybe with an amplifier or oscillator

[image: pattern generator]

I don't understand **what modulation system** allow this "driving" signal between this different devices (TEM, pattern generator, computer..) to generate correctly *template-pattern* for final printing on wafer ?

To *print* a chip project from design (software) you need to generate a modulation to communicate with pattern generator device and this pattern generator device needs to communicate with TEM but you need still a modulation to *tell* what TEM should print and *how* to print 

What type of modulation or what system/component is used to modulate different signals between this devices ?

*Indeed* we must *generate* an interference *before*

> Diffraction cannot be explained using a particle view of light (geometrical or ray optics); it requires a wave interpretation (physical optics), according to which any image is actually an interference pattern formed by light rays that take different paths to reach the same point in the image

But *still before* generating this interference to have correct diffraction electrons used to print a pattern on wafer (we use a TEM system) **you need a *correct* modulation**. 

 What and how signal generating check if this modulation system is correct to ensure that the devices understand each other ?

One of technique use something like `Electron backscatter diffraction`

Comment: First of all, your picture shows an SEM (*scanning* electron microscope), not a TEM. An SEM modified to produce ion beams ([FIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focused_ion_beam)) is sometimes used to modify chips during the debugging process, but is too expensive to use to make chips from scratch. I personally have never heard of anyone using dynamically-generated patterns to create electron diffraction masks for chip production. Do you have any actual references for this?

Comment: No, I thought that the method was this .. sorry

Comment: I look now but only thing that I found is [THIS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03305v1.pdf) but here we talk molecular motors and I really don't know if something like this it can be implemented like signal modulation driving to make electron diffraction masks, I think that we need another process to make masks but maybe with some quantum techniques in future we create pattern  inducing a form from inside the material to internal directly without 'writing' with a laser like 'traditional lithograpy